# Trying to install rpm package in Fedora 21, but dependency on OpenJDK 7 results in errors

Tags: linux, fedora, java, dependencies

I am running Fedora 21 32bit workstation version.

Trying to install iris-4.22.0-1.noarch.rpm:

```
[itse@localhost Downloads]$ sudo yum install iris-4.22.0-1.noarch.rpm
[sudo] password for itse: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Examining iris-4.22.0-1.noarch.rpm: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
Marking iris-4.22.0-1.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package iris.noarch 0:4.22.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk for package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql-jdbc for package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql-server for package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package iris.noarch 0:4.22.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk for package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
---> Package postgresql-jdbc.noarch 0:9.3.1102-1.fc21 will be installed
---> Package postgresql-server.i686 0:9.3.5-5.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql-libs(x86-32) = 9.3.5-5.fc21 for package: postgresql-server-9.3.5-5.fc21.i686
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql(x86-32) = 9.3.5-5.fc21 for package: postgresql-server-9.3.5-5.fc21.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5 for package: postgresql-server-9.3.5-5.fc21.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package iris.noarch 0:4.22.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk for package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch
---> Package postgresql.i686 0:9.3.5-5.fc21 will be installed
---> Package postgresql-libs.i686 0:9.3.5-5.fc21 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: iris-4.22.0-1.noarch (/iris-4.22.0-1.noarch)
           Requires: java-1.7.0-openjdk
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The error states a dependency on java-1.7.0-openjdk, but as I understand Fedora 21 uses java-1.8.0-openjdk.

How do I overcome this dependency? As I understand packages dependent on OpenJDK 7, should be able to also work on OpenJDK 8.

I tried to manually install the OpenJDK7 rpm downloaded from this link: http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/20/i386/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686.html

The installation failed with the following error:

```
[itse@localhost Downloads]$ sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686.rpm
[sudo] password for itse: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Examining java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686.rpm: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686
Marking java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 for package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 for package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 for package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-14.fc21 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-14.fc21.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-14.fc21.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20 for package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686
---> Package ttmkfdir.i686 0:3.0.9-44.fc21 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686 (/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.i686)
           Requires: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can I just install OpenJDK 8 and somehow remove the dependency on OpenJDK 7 since 8 is backwards compatible with 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Installed OpenJDK 8 instead of 7 since version 8 is backwards compatible with 7.
Installed the two listed decencies separately: postgresql-jdbc and postgresql-server
Installed using: rpm -i --nodeps iris-4.22.0-1.noarch.rpm